# Do neutrals spawn in 1v1 Mid Mode

Tags: dota-2

Talking about the matchmaking 1v1 mode that was implemented:

Do neutrals spawn in that mode?

I could not test it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All neutrals spawn as normal

> Only the mid-lane spawns creeps. All neutral creeps spawn as per usual and so do the runes. There is only you and 1 opponent against each other. [(source)](http://forum.gamesports.net/dota/showthread.php?92015-New-quot-Practice-1v1-quot-Game-mode) (*Not an official quote*)

However the first rune does not spawn [(source)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Game_modes).

On [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/28jv4v/just_a_quick_question_why_do_neutrals_spawn_in/) they explain why there are neutrals: consider it a practice mode.

Comment: Strange. DotA 2 wiki said something else about runes: "First rune does not spawn. " http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Game_modes

Comment: There is nothing for neutrals? Just that the middle lane is spawning

Comment: @Wandang indeed first rune doesn't spawn to reduce the chances of seeing an early double damage that would be a huge advantage for the person picking it up. For the next runes, it's not so much of a problem because rune control is a technical aspect of the 1v1 matchup

Comment: @Mathias711 please add that the first rune does not spawn and that the quote is not entirely correct. Then i can upvote and accept :)